# How to use Pendrive in a USB disabled Computer?

Tags: linux, usb, linux-mint

The computer (study lab computer) that I am using has its USB disabled, hence I cannot run or copy the programs that I have in my pen-drive.

How can I run  or view the contents in my pen drive.

OS: Linux Mint

Comment: Ask the administrator to have it enabled.

Comment: Already asked them but they are not willing to enable it. They are afraid that the computer might get infected by  virus. But I always use Kaspersky AV at home and it didn't detect any virus. So my pen drive is virus free

Comment: Generally, if the functionality is disabled, it is disabled for a **reason**.

Comment: The only reason they disabled it is to keep the computer virus free. But I assure you there are no harmful virus in my pen drive. Besides I just want to view a text file.

Comment: They have no way to know or verify that, however, without exposing themselves to unnecessary risk. It's not something that can be forcibly circumvented, nor should it be. You might want to consider a service along the lines of Dropbox instead.

Comment: Like Rilgon says, consider Dropbox (in a few days there will also be [GoogleDrive](http://drive.google.com)) or, send email-attachments to yourself (usually saving them as draft-copy is sufficient if you can login from school and home).

Comment: Looks like from next time I will have to upload my files somewhere and then download it to this computer.

Comment: You could make the point that allowing internet access opens a lot more avenues of spreading malware than a flash drive.. though that could backfire resulting in no internet access depending on how paranoid they are.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Ask the administrator to enable it
2. Download your files from the Internet
3. Use a different medium, such as a DVD to bring your own files

Answer (score -2):

Open the Windows Registry and open the following key
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\ Control\StorageDevicePolicies

Now add a new DWORD called WriteProtect and put the value as 0 to disable write privileges to the USB port. To reverse the step, either delete the WriteProtect REG_DWORD or toggle the value to 1 which will enable the port.

This trick will work only on XP SP2

Comment: I think they disabled the USB from BIOS, so will this trick work ?

Comment: There is another way to Enable or Disable USB Port through Registry. Search for the Key “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor”
Select the key UsbStor , double click on Start value.
In “Value data” enter 4 to disable USB storage  , or enter 3 to enable USB storage on windows system.

Comment: The question specified Linux Mint as the OS, not Windows..?

Comment: Thanks I will try this method in my computer (win 7) when I get back home ^_^

Comment: how in the world will you test it when you say you're using Linux? @Failed_Noob

Comment: @Sathya In my Lab-Computer (i.e in my college) they use Linux Mint and at home I have Windows 7